# Select a specific slice of data from a main dataframe, conditional on a value in a main dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a main dataframe (df) with a Date column (non-index), a column 'VXX_Full' with values, and a 'signal' column.

I want to iterate through the signals column, and whenever it is 1, i want to capture a slice (20 rows before, 40 rows after) of the 'VXX_Full' column and create a new dataframe with all the slices. I would like the column name of the new dataframe to be the row number of the original dataframe.

```
VXX_signal = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((60,0)))

counter = 1

for row in df.index:

if df.loc[row,'signal'] == 1:
    add_row = df.loc[row - 20:row +20,'VXX_Full']
    VXX_signal[counter] = add_row
    counter +=1

VXX_signal
```

It just doesn't seem to be working. It creates a dataframe, however the values are all Nan. The first slice, it at least appears to be getting data from the main df, however the data doesn't correspond to the correct location. The following set of columns (there are 30 signals so 30 columns created) in the new df are all NaN

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about your current code - but basically all you need is a list of ranges of indexes. If your index is linear, this would be something like:

```
indexes = list(df[df.signal==1].index)
ranges = [(i,list(range(i-20,i+21))) for i in indexes] #create tuple (original index,range)
dfs = [df.loc[i[1]].copy().rename(
                    columns={'VXX_Full':i[0]}).reset_index(drop=True) for i in ranges]
#EDIT: for only the VXX_Full Column:
dfs = [df.loc[i[1]].copy()[['VXX_Full']].copy().rename(
                    columns={'VXX_Full':i[0]}).reset_index(drop=True) for i in ranges]
#here we take the -20:+20 slice of df, make a separate dataframe, the
#we change 'VXX_Full' to the original index value, and reset index to give it 0:40 index.
#The new index will be useful when putting all the columns next to each other.
```

So we made a list of indexes with signal == 1, turned it into a list of ranges and finally a list of dataframes with reset index.
Now we want to merge it all together:

```
from functools import reduce
merged_df = reduce(lambda left, right: pd.merge(
                          left, right, left_index=True, right_index=True), dfs)
```

Comment: That appears to work to some extent, 'ranges' creates the right set of tuples.
But it copies over all the columns from the original df (there are 10+) - i would only like the VXX_Full column. I have tried to amend to 
    dfs = [df.loc[i[1],'VXX_Full'].copy().rename(
                    columns={'VXX_Full':i[0]}).reset_index(drop=True) for i in ranges]

but no luck, it says:
 can not merge DataFrame with instance of type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

Comment: That's an annoying detail - you just need to make sure this remains a dataframe. Fixed above. Basically `df[[col]]` is a dataframe but `df.loc[:,col]` is a Series.

Comment: That has worked, but because you had renamed VXX_Full to i[0], you couldn't grab just that column. But renaming to [i[0]] has worked. Thanks!

Any idea why the original code didn't work? i was stuck on it for a while and I seemed to be close, but just transporting the lists into the new df wasn't working

Comment: Fixed - I didn't think that one through properly -_-. Your original code seems incomplete since you seem to be assigning the new dataframe to a column in the old dataframe. Is some code missing?

Answer (score 0):

I would build the resulting dataframe from a dictionnary of lists:

```
resul = pd.DataFrame({i:df.loc[i-20 if i >=20 else 0: i+40 if i <= len(df) - 40 else len(df), 
                               'VXX_FULL'].values for i in df.loc[df.signal == 1].index})
```

The trick is that `.values` extract a numpy array with no associated index.

Beware: above code assumes that the index of the original dataframe is just the row number. Use `reset_index` first if it is different.